File attachment link error in angular 'This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it'
I get this error when I try to open up a file attachment in angular code. I tried to research this error but haven't found a clear answer yet and not one specific to angular or typescript. I'm using a window.open method in a function to open the file in a new window and this is the error I get

In my html file I have a Filename cell with a click event to call open Attachment function
<div *ngIf="!isLoadingDocuments && !tableDataSource?.data.length" class="text-center 
empty-card-height">
<p class="mb-0">No vendor documents on file</p>
</div>

<div [class.hidden]="isLoadingDocuments || !tableDataSource?.data.length">
 <div *ngIf="tableDataSource?.data.length" class="card-header p-3">
  <lf-material-search (updated)="tableDataSource.filter = $event;"></lf-material- 
  search>
</div>
<div class="add-scroller table-responsive">
<mat-table [dataSource]="tableDataSource"
           matSort
           matSortActive="filename"
           matSortDirection="asc"
           matSortDisableClear="true"
   >
    <!-- filename -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Filename</mat-header- 
    cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let document">
            <a (click)="fetchVendorDocument(document, true);">
                {{document.name}}
            </a>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- uploader -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="uploader">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="add-min-width">Uploader</mat- 
    header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let document" class="add-min-width">
                        <span
                            *ngIf="document.user.memberships && 
  document.user.memberships.length > 0 && document.user.memberships[0].profile"
                        >{{document.user.memberships[0].profile.givenNames}} 
    {{document.user.memberships[0].profile.familyName}}</span>
            <span
                *ngIf="!document.user.memberships || 
     document.user.memberships.length === 0 && document.user.profile"> 
    {{document.user.profile.givenNames}} 
    {{document.user.profile.familyName}}</span>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- upload date -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="createdAt">
        <mat-header-cell class="add-min-width" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort- 
        header>Uploaded time
        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell class="add-min-width" *matCellDef="let document">
            {{document.createdAt | legfiDate:'MM/DD/YYYY  h:mm a'}}
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- filesize -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="filesize">
        <mat-header-cell class="narrower" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>File 
   size
        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell class="narrower" *matCellDef="let document">
            {{document.filesize | legfiFilesize}}
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- actions -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
        <mat-header-cell class="d-flex justify-content-end" *matHeaderCellDef>
            Actions
        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let document" class="d-flex justify-content-end">
            <div class="text-right">
                <button class="btn btn-link"
                        [matMenuTriggerFor]="columnsMenu"
                        [attr.aria-label]="'actions'">
                    <i class="custom-more"></i>
                </button>
                <mat-menu #columnsMenu="matMenu" class="pb-0">
                    <ng-container *ngIf="document.model !== 'payable'">
                        <button mat-menu-item 
 (click)="fetchVendorDocument(document)">
                            {{ 'Upload Document' }}
                        </button>
                        <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="hasWriteAccess" 
 (click)="startDocumentRename(document);">
                                {{ 'Edit Document' }}
                        </button>

                        <button mat-menu-item *ngIf="hasWriteAccess" 
  (click)="startDeleteVendorDocument(document);">
                            {{ 'Delete' }}
                        </button>
                    </ng-container>
                </mat-menu>
            </div>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- template items -->
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat- 
     header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
 </mat-table>
 </div>

typescript is where I'm setting the openAttachment function
export class VendorDocumentsComponent implements OnInit
{
  vendorId: number = 0;
  vendor: Vendor;
  /** docs table **/
 displayedColumns: string[] = [
   'name',
   'createdAt',
    'uploader',
    'filesize',
    'actions',
  ];
 tableDataSource: MatTableDataSource<VendorDocument> = null;
 searchValue = '';
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
/** state */
 jwt: JwtLegFiClaims;
 isLoadingDocuments: boolean = true;
 hasWriteAccess: boolean = false;
 hasReadAccess: boolean = false;

constructor(
    private _billPayVendorService: VendorService,
    private _growler: GrowlerService,
    private _matDialogService: MatDialog,
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
   ) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.jwt = LegFiJwtService.read();

this.hasReadAccess = LegFiJwtService.doesUserHaveModulePermission(
        'billpay',
        false,
);
this.hasWriteAccess = LegFiJwtService.doesUserHaveModulePermission(
        'billpay',
        true,
);

this.vendorId = +extractRoute(this._activatedRoute, 
 VendorDetailsComponent).snapshot.parent.params['id'];
 if (this.hasReadAccess) {
    this.getVendorInformation();
     this.getVendorDocuments();
  } else {
    this.isLoadingDocuments = false;
   }
}

getVendorInformation(): void {
   this.isLoadingDocuments = true;
   this._billPayVendorService
        .getOrgVendorDetails(null, this.vendorId)
        .pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
        .subscribe(
                {
                    next: (billPayVendor: Vendor) => {
                        this.vendor = billPayVendor;
                        this.isLoadingDocuments = false;
                    },
                    error: () => {
                        this._growler.oops(
                                'There was a problem loading this vendor.',
                        );
                    },
                },
        );
  }


  openAttachment(url: string) {
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  }

/** They clicked to upload files */
 showDocumentUploaderDialog() {
    this._matDialogService.open(MultiDocumentUploaderDialogComponent, {
      width: MatDialogSizes.MD,
    data: <MultiDocumentUploaderDialogInput>{
        type: 'vendor',
        vendor: this.vendor,
    },
 }).afterClosed().subscribe(
        (result: GenericDialogResult) => {
            if (result?.success) {
                this.getVendorDocuments();
            }
        },
    );
}


The error in xml file Access Denied - indicates that you don't have permission to view that file.

@zdd Doesn't make sense .That file is in a local folder on my computer and I can open it any time except when I click on it from this page and then I get this error. On another page, set up differently, I can view this file. So what do I do to get permission? Is there something in that file to get permission or is that something in the code to fix? This has to be code related that I need assistance with .

Where did you call this method: openAttachment, I didn't see that in your template.

@zdd scroll down in my second code block which is the typescript code. It's near the bottom of that code.

Do you know what is an anuglar template? where did you call this method in template? not where did you define this method.

@zdd I'm not sure exactly what you mean? Are you talking about openAttachment? If so I'm calling it in the ts file which I have in my original post.
